# Hyper-V 2016 with physical RAID Disk for Files: pass through or discrete device assignment or what?

Tags: hyper-v, file-sharing, hyper-v-server-2016

I've installed a new physical server with Hyper-V Core 2016 on it. I got "two" drives on the physical machine:

1. NVMe (M.2 2280 Samsung 960 Pro) with two partition:

   - C:\ = 80 GB = for the physical system OS (Hyper-V Core 2016)
   - D:\ = 900 GB = for all the VHD/VHDX Files
2. SATA RAID6 (8x 4GB SATA over LSI MegaRAID SAS 9361-8i = ~26GB "Drive")

   - ?? = For all Data/Files/Documents

**What is the best way on Hyper-V in this scenario to use the SATA Drive as a "File Share"?** 
I think of something like VT-d, Drive or PCI-Raid-Card pass-through to a virtual File Server (Windows Server 2016)? So that my physical Server just serves as a Hyper-V Server and can ignore the RAID-Card/RAID-Drives. What is the best way to achieve that?

1. Passthrough Disk? Taking the RAID-Disk offline on the physical system and then add it over the hyper-v manager to the virtual file system? But then I can’t manage the RAID? Or have to manage the RAID on the physical OS?
2. Discrete Device Assignment? Using the new feature from Hyper-V 2016 to passthrough the RAID-Card (PCIx) to the virtual file system? Is that even possible?
3. Create a VHDX on the RAID-Disk and add that Disk to the File-System as secondary Drive on which I can deploy the files?
4. Other possibility?

MANY THANKS!

Comment: Forget options 1 and 2. Create a VHD(X) on the SATA drives and attach that to the VM.

Comment: So you would recommend to create a partition (with allocation unit size 64k) on the RAID Disk on the physical host and create one big VHDX (dynamic resizing) and attach it to the virtual file server?

Answer (score 3):

Pass-through disks are no longer recommended. They no longer provide higher performance than virtual disks, they aren't supported much beyond basic support, they make backups harder, they have a lack of third-party tools and they make portability harder.

Creating a VHDX and using that virtual disk would be what I suggest.

To read more about why pass-through disks are a bad idea, have a look at this article by Eric Siron: http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-pass-through-disks/

Comment: What about the new "Discrete Device Assignment" Feature?

Answer (score 1):

For a fileserver, you mostly need size flexibility, thin provisioning and snapshots, rather than pure speed and/or low overhead.

I strongly suggest you to discard both passthrough and direct assignement disks; rather, make good use of the features guaranteed by virtual disk images (VHDX images).